# CakePHP How to make search with query in URL

Tags: forms, cakephp, search, cakephp-1.3

I have a search form in the header of my site. it takes me to a certain controller/action when i click submit. So far so good.

However, I would like the loaded page to have a url with the query in it, such as

```
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=eminem
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Is setting form action to `GET` sufficient? If not, you may want to look at the `P`ost-`R`edirect-`G`et pattern.

Comment: aah right, GET instead of POST! duh!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a [Post-Redirect->Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Our [search plugin](https://github.com/cakedc/search) has a component and a bunch of more magic to automate this. Use it or take a look at the code to get the idea.